# Repository Pattern with multiple tables

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

Recently I have been reading up on using the repository pattern and DI to help create easily testable code, I think I understand it for the most part. However I'm having difficulty with one issue. I need to create a Rules object for my applications business layer. To create a rule, I need the ability to read and write to two tables. How would you go about implementing a repository that uses two tables for one object?

for example:

```
ICollection<type> GetAllRules();
```

What would I put in for type as it requires two tables?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: It sounds like the rule is an aggregate of the two underlying entities plus some logic. So you would keep the two repositories separate and use a "Domain Service" to create a rule, which would interact with the repositories. The application layer then interacts with the Rule Domain Service.

Comment: Recently I had the same problem. I used Base class having all common properties and then used dynamic object to get the data. But later we changed the Rules table to be a single Ruleset table with versions of data. This way the data is more relational and we don't have to work with dynamic object. In future if have a new set of rules just add them to the table and assign a version number. Not sure if this would help you, but thought worth sharing my experience.

Comment: Kinda hard to answer this but I would maybe try ICollection<Rule> GetAllRules(); Where Rule has all the fields you expect a rule to have. The point of a repository is that you hide the underlying table structure. So for example if a rules id is made up of it's name + internal id number but the table stores these in separate columns then GetAllRules does the mapping from what's in the DB and exposes this as ID to everyone who want's.

Comment: Thanks KingDave , I'm going to try your approach

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wouldn't insist on having a repository for that.

As Fowler says

> Conceptually, a Repository encapsulates the set of objects persisted in a data store and the operations performed over them, providing a more object-oriented view of the persistence layer.

This is probably why most implementations tend to expose pure domain objects rather than derivatives (which your Rule object seems to be).

I would have two repositories for the two tables you mention, then I would have a unit of work to expose all repositories and then I would have a business layer service responsible for the compound processing.

An advantage of such approach would be that the repository layer remains clean, there is no business processing involved here, no unclear rules introduced to the persistence layer.

Comment: I have been looking into your approach and have a question. In my service class , how to use my Save or getRule methods to return two tables as one object?

Comment: Take a look how unit of work works. You have both repositories available which allows you to write queries on both. Depending on whether or not you want to expose a generic IQueryable or specific methods, the way of retrieving data can vary slightly. There is one of tutorials available http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application